# Python - How to give __init__ values to other classes

Tags: python, class, init, super

Im new into Python and having some troubles when it comes to give **init** value from one class to another.

I have read about using super() function could be an extreme easy way to give the values from one class to another however I am not quite there with the knowledge and having trouble with it and I am not sure if that is also what I am looking for.

For now I have coded something simple as:

```
Class 1:


from classOne import printClass


class classOne:

    def __init__(self):
        self.test = "test"
        self.hello = "hello"
        self.world = "world"

    def main(self,):

        printClass.printFunction(#Send init values#)


test = classOne()
test.main()

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

Class 2:


class printClass():


    def printFunction(test, hello, world):
        print(test)
        print(hello)
        print(world)


printClass()
```

and I wonder how I can send from class 1 the init values to class 2 so I can print out those **init** from class 1 inside the class 2?

Comment: you say that you are a newbie, and playing around with super is not what I would recommend for newbies to do. What is your actual problem at hand, and can it be reformulated to not include `super`? I think that will make your life eaiser, or you're here for the learning, but then you really should have an example not working as you think it ought to and that example should include `super`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, as the method `printfunction` is not static, you need a instance of class `printclass` then pass the values as parameters

```
printClass().printFunction(self.test, self.hello, self.world)
```

You coud also have a static function in printclass if there is no specific param to the instance

```
class printClass:
    @statticmethod
    def printFunction(test, hello, world):
        print(test)
        print(hello)
        print(world)
```

The call would be

```
printClass.printFunction(self.test, self.hello, self.world)
```

Comment: Oh okey that make also sense. What is the idea of using super() function in this type of scenario if you might know? - Also you wrote stattic with 2 t's :)

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie there is no purpose of using super() here. super() Is when clas inherit from another, it's parent class can be accessed using super()

Comment: Couldn't we make class 2 inherit from class 1 to retrieve the values implicitely?

Comment: @Guimoute nope, heritage is when purpose asked for it, not to pass data, your code is the way to do if a printclass is needed to do special stuff

Comment: Static methods are really questionable.... If a method doesn't interact with the state of the object to which it belongs, why is it defined as part of the class at all?

Comment: @Guimoute If it answerse your post, I let you accept an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have private class members. This means that any member of a class (or a member of any instance of that class) can be accessed directly and without restriction from outside. So you can do something like this:

```
class classOne:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = "test"
        self.hello = "hello"
        self.world = "world"


class classTwo:
    def __init__(self, class_one):
        self.test = class_one.test
        self.hello = class_one.hello
        self.world = class_one.world
    def printFunction(self):
        print(self.test)
        print(self.hello)
        print(self.world)
```

Then you can do this:

```
>>> class_one = classOne()
>>> class_two = classTwo(class_one)
>>> class_two.printFunction()
```

Or if you wanted `classTwo` to inherit from `classOne`, you could do this :

File: module_one.py:

```
class ClassOne:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = "test"
        self.hello = "hello"
        self.world = "world"
```

File: module_two.py:

```
import module_one

class ClassTwo(module_one.ClassOne):
    def printFunction(self):
        print(self.test)
        print(self.hello)
        print(self.world)
```

This works because `classTwo` inherits the values of `test`, `hello`, and `world` from `classOne`. Using it is almost the same, but `classTwo` no longer takes an instance of `classOne` in its constructor:

```
>>> import module_two
>>> c2 = module_two.ClassTwo()
>>> c2.printFunction()
```

Comment: I tried to use your second with `Or if you wanted classTwo to inherit from classOne, you could do this:` but I believe I am having hard time with importing since I have two classes sepereted in two different scripts. Is it still possible to do that?

Comment: Sure, you can do that. I the file where `classTwo` is defined, just import the file that has `classOne`

Comment: Im getting an error with: `    c2 = module_two.ClassTwo()
AttributeError: module 'module_two' has no attribute 'ClassTwo'` - and I followed ur code :( But what I did was I created a def main(): inside the ClassOne where I call `c2.printFunction()` inside the main. Would that work?

Comment: If you added the usual `if __name__=="__main__":` to module two, it will still work, but in that case, since you're already defining it inside `module_two` itself: (1) don't need to `import module_two` and (2) remove the module name from the definition of `c2` (second line would be `c2 = ClassTwo()`)